# Javascript works locally, will not work on webserver

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I have a banner which has eight links that remain static on the banner.  When you click one, the background is supposed to slide to the left or right to goto the corresponding picture.  This all works great on my local machine, but when I upload it to my webserver, the javascript doesn't seem to do anything.  As far as I can tell, it's loaded. but the links, when clicked, don't respond.

I should note that I'm moving HTML I've created over to a PHP page, and I've heard that PHP doesn't interact with JS initially, but that shouldn't affect just HTML, right?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fc4y7/) link.

**HTML**

```
<div id='main-banner-space'>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">

        <div id="slide1" class="main-slide">
            <div id="slidetext">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide1 -->

        <div id="slide2" class="main-slide">
             <div id="slidetext">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide2 -->

        <div id="slide3" class="main-slide">
            <div id="slidetextb">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide3 -->

        <div id="slide4" class="main-slide">
            <div id="slidetext">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide4 -->

        <div id="slide5" class="main-slide">
            <div id="slidetext">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide5 -->

        <div id="slide6" class="main-slide">
            <div id="slidetextb">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide6 -->

        <div id="slide7" class="main-slide">
            <div id="slidetext">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide7 -->

        <div id="slide8" class="main-slide">
            <div id="slidetext">
                text
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of slide8 -->

    </div> <!-- end of slider-wrapper -->  

    <div id='menu'>
        <div id='link1'>link</div>
        <div id='link2'>link</div>
        <div id='link3'>link</div>
        <div id='link4'>link</div>
        <div id='link5'>link</div>
        <div id='link6'>link</div>
        <div id='link7'>link</div>
        <div id='link8'>link</div>
    </div>
</div><!--end of main-banner-space-->
```

**CSS**

```
a#banner { text-decoration:none; }

#main-banner-space {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:930px;
    height:320px;
    top: 10px;
    left:-5px;
    border: 1px solid #dad8d8;
}

#menu {
    position:absolute;
    height:320px;
    width:260px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    top:0px;
    left:-5px;
}

.slider-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    width:9000px;
    height:100%;
}

.main-slide {
    position:relative;
    width:930px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

#slide1 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/1.png);}
#slide2 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/2.png);}
#slide3 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/3.png);}
#slide4 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/4.png);}
#slide5 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/5.png);}
#slide6 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/6.png);}
#slide7 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/7.png);}
#slide8 {width:930px; background-image:url(../_Images/8.png);}

#link1 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}
#link2 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}
#link3 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}
#link4 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}
#link5 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}
#link6 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}
#link7 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}
#link8 {height:40px; width:250px; background-image:url(../_Images/menuP.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;color:#000;line-height:250%;padding-left:10px;font-family:Arial;}

#link1:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }
#link2:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }
#link3:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }
#link4:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }
#link5:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }
#link6:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }
#link7:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }
#link8:hover { cursor:pointer; background-position: 0 -40px; }

#slidetext {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:660px;
    left:270px;
    top:220px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-style:italic;
}

#slidetextb {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:660px;
    left:270px;
    top:220px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
    // find all slides
    var slides = $('.main-slide');
    // starting index
    // click listener
    $('#link1').click(function(){
        // index
        i = 1;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(0).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
    $('#link2').click(function(){
        // index
        i = 2;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(1).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
    $('#link3').click(function(){
        //index
        i = 3;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(2).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
    $('#link4').click(function(){
        // index
        i = 4;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(3).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
    $('#link5').click(function(){
        //index
        i=5;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(4).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
    $('#link6').click(function(){
        // index
        i=6;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(5).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
    $('#link7').click(function(){
        // index
        i=7;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(6).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
    $('#link8').click(function(){
        // index 
        i=8;
        // scroll to that index
        $('.slider-wrapper').animate(
            {'left' : -(slides.eq(7).position().left)},
            800
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your javascript located in relation to the give html?

Comment: Are you including correctly your JS file and jQuery?

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your syntax for the jQuery ready event (if that's your intent) is correct. Changing your JavaScript to the following fixes your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fc4y7/1/).

```
$(function() {
...
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: To expand on this explanation a little more. By using the dollar sign function in this post, it tells Javascript when you start executing your self executing function. This binds it to the domready event so it begins executing when the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait to load the DOM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Your Code goes here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fc4y7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what Nathan Harkenrider wrote, it's possible you were confusing two similar looking things.

**1)** This an immediately-invoked function expression that allows you to set up a module scope for your code as well as allowing you to pass parameters in from "the outside". In this example we're passing in jQuery as `$`.

```
(function ($) {
  // code here
}(jQuery));
```

**2)** The second, as was mentioned, was jQuery's alternative `document.ready` function which looks similar but is different.

You can use either this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // code here
});
```

Or this:

```
$(function () {
  // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
(function ($) {
```

instead use

```
$(function() {
```

which is shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```